# What are the differences between swap in C++ and Python?

Tags: python, swap

About `swap`, in C++, we can swap two by `std::swap(x, y);`.
`x` and `y` are passed into swap as `reference`.

But in Python, can we also write a `swap` function which can do the swap the same way as in C++?
The Python version of swap I implemented is kinda stupid:

```
def swap_in_python(x, y):
    return y, x

#so when swapping a and b, I usually do it like this
a, b = swap_in_python(a, b)
```

This is really cumbersome, but we can't pass `reference or pointer` as what we can do in C++, right?

**EDIT:**

Is there any other way not employing assignment(not using =)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, in Python, it's much more elegant:

```
(a,b) = (b,a)
```

You don't have to call a function at all. And, yes, as per the comments, the parentheses are unnecessary here. I still prefer them since I believe they make the intent clearer.

---

Following edit:

> Is there any other way not employing assignment (not using `=`)?

Possibly, though I don't know of one, and I can't imagine it would be simpler or more readable than the basic way shown above. If you're looking for a *more* complicated way of doing things that can be done simply, might I suggest that you're in the wrong mindset? :-)

Comment: You can leave out the parens.

Comment: Yeah, that's a habit I got into early since it makes it look different to the C `a, b=a, b` which does something _totally_ different. I actually prefer the list-type variant since it makes the intent clearer (IMNSHO) :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, so to do swap in Python, we gotta to use =, right?

Comment: Do we have to? I don't know. There may well be a closure/lambda/advanced method of doing it that doesn't involve `=` but I don't know of one (and it would almost be _less_ readable than the alternative) - I prefer the basic language since I mostly use it for teaching youngsters who have a hard enough time understanding variables, let alone lambdas - I want my beautiful language back :-)

Comment: This does something completely different to C++'s `std::swap`. In C++, `std::swap` swaps the values of two objects, `(a, b) = (b, a)` swaps which objects two references refer two. Consider `c=["hello","world"]; d=[]; a=c; b=d; a,b=b,a` vs `std::list<std::string> c, d;c.push_back("hello"); c.push_back("world"); std::list<std::string> &a = c, &b = d; std::swap( a, b );`

Comment: Charles, that seems a irrelevant point to me and simply an effect of the Python "everything is an object accessed by reference" nature. The _effect_ in both cases is the same in that whenever you now use the second "object" it will contain the first "data" (and vice versa)

Comment: @paxdiablo: I think the difference between the Python object model and C++ object model is very relevant to the question. The swap technique you have shown only affects the values denoted by two references, the C++ when you swap the value of two objects any expressions that denote the two objects being swapped will see the change in value. Yes, the questioner's answer also didn't have the same effect as `std::swap` either. I don't know of a generic way to do a `std::swap` in python for mutable objects myself, but the difference is important.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that it is possible to *simply* implement the equivalent of C++'s swap in Python.

This is due to the fundamental differences between the C++ object model and the Python object model. In python all variables reference objects. With the swap that you have implemented, all that happens is the the objects referred to by the two variables are exchanged. The objects themselves are untouched so nothing referring to the existing objects will see any change.

In C++'s `std::swap`, the values of the two objects are exchanged so any expression denoting either of the objects being swapped will see the changes.

```
>>> c = [ "hello", "world" ]
>>> d = []
>>> a = c
>>> b = d
>>> a, b = swap_in_python(a, b)
>>> c
['hello', 'world']
>>> d
[]
>>>
```

vs

```
std::list<std::string> c, d;
c.push_back("hello");
c.push_back("world");
std::list<std::string> &a = c, &b = d;
std::swap( a, b ); // c is empty, d is "hello", "world"
```

Answer (score 1):

Python passes by pointer.

Simpler swap:

```
x, y = y, x
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just directly write

```
a, b = (b, a)
```